# Allow popup bubble to "break out" of jQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

In a jQuery UI dialog I am displaying a list of choices (checkboxes). Each node in the list has a help icon at the end of it, on which a popup bubble with info will be shown on hover.

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog" class="hidden">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk1"/> <label for="chk1">Node 1</label> <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/24/Categories-system-help-icon.png" class="nodeTrigger" />
            <div class="popup hidden">
                <span class="bold">Node 1</span><br/>
                Some Long description of what Node 1 entails
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk2"/> <label for="chk2">Node 2</label> <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/24/Categories-system-help-icon.png" class="nodeTrigger" />
            <div class="popup hidden">
                <span class="bold">Node 2</span><br/>
                Some Long description of what Node 2 entails
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chk3"/> <label for="chk3">Node 3</label> <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/24/Categories-system-help-icon.png" class="nodeTrigger" />
            <div class="popup hidden">
                <span class="bold">Node 3</span><br/>
                Some Long description of what Node 3 entails
            </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#dialog {
    position: relative;    
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.bold {
    font-weight: bold;   
}

.popup {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 400px;
}
```

JavaScript (in a jQuery ready function):

```
$('img.nodeTrigger').hover(
    function(e){
        var that = $(this);
        var position = that.position();

        var popup = $(that.parent().find('div.popup').get(0));
        var top = position.top - (popup.outerHeight() / 2.0) + (that.outerHeight() / 2.0);
        var left = position.left + that.outerWidth() + 5;
        popup.stop(true, true)
        .css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top': top, 'left': left, 'z-index': 99999 })
        .fadeIn('slow');
    },
    function(){
        var popup = $(this).parent().find('div.popup');
        popup.stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');   
    }
);

$('#dialog-trigger').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        title: 'Choose some items',
        buttons: {
            'Ok': function() { $(this).dialog('close'); }   
        }
    });
});
```

You can see a basic example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/YZpzN/6/

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to allow the popup bubble to break out of the dialog. When the bubble is shown, it is contained inside the dialog, resulting in scrollbars. I need to it "break out", overlaying the dialog if necessary.

**UPDATE**: While @flec's answer solves the immediate problem, it does not entirely suit my needs. There may be many choices in the dialog, which means the dialog itself may need a vertical scrollbar to keep it reasonably sized. It is also acceptable that the popup is replaced by a div on the right side of the dialog if thats possible (like having an info box on the right, of the div, over the overlay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your CSS to this:

```
#dialog {
    position: relative;   
    overflow: visible;
}
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YZpzN/7/

Comment: Awesome.. One question though.. There may be alot of choices in the dialog, meaning it may need a vertical scrollbar to keep the dialog a reasonable size.. Won't this fix make that impossible?

Comment: I guess so. There is an `overflow-x` in CSS3 but I did not manage to get to work. Maybe you can work with another div inside your dialog-div.

Comment: I can't really seem to get it to work either. I'm entirely open to changing the HTML, or if necessary, put like an info box on the right side of the div (same z-index as the div etc), so the info bubble is always outside the div.. Maybe that is easier?

Comment: @MortenJacobsen I guess you are right. I think you should put the info-div outside the dialog-div. And use `position: absolute` to position it on hover.

Comment: I managed to put the info bubble outside the dialog, aligned on the right. Still, if you dont need scrolling inside the div, this answer works, so I'm accepting it.